# Create Cache listview of my data populated from the server

Tags: java, android, caching

I want to create a cache that stores present listview populated from the server which means even if users are not online they can have access to the listview data been loaded before going offline. These are my codes that contains the swipelistlayout and the main class Tab4

```
public class Tab4 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private int index;
    ImageSwitcher switcher;
    android.os.Handler Handler = new android.os.Handler();

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private ListView listView;


    private String URL_TOP_250 = "http://172.126.43.152/locator/test/refractor2.php?offset=";

    private int offSet = 0;

    private static final String TAG = Tab1.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_4,container,false);


        listView = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list4);

        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        // Adding request to request queue
//Editted        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //getView().setOnClickListener();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        fetchMovies();
                                    }
                                }
        );



        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), Newbies.class);

                //String text = String.valueOf(movieList.get(position));
                String text = movieList.get(position).getSlug();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Newbies.class);
                i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });




    }




    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        fetchMovies();
    }


    private void fetchMovies() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // appending offset to url
        String url = URL_TOP_250 + offSet;

        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to movies list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject movieObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    // Movie m = new Movie();

                                    int rank = movieObj.getInt("rank");
                                    String title = movieObj.getString("postTitle");
                                    String author = movieObj.getString("postAuthor");
                                    String slug = movieObj.getString("postSlug");
                                    String categories = "technologies";
                                    String thumbnailUrl =  movieObj.getString("postPic");
                                    String year = movieObj.getString("postDate");


                                    Movie m = new Movie(rank, title, author, slug, categories, thumbnailUrl, year);

                                    movieList.add(0, m);

                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (rank >= offSet)
                                        offSet = rank;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }


}
```

And the SwipeListAdapter class is below...

```
public class SwipeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private String[] bgColors;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public SwipeListAdapter(Activity tab1, List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.activity = tab1;
        this.movieList = movieList;
        bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        //String slug;
        TextView category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieList.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        author.setText(m.getAuthor());
       // slug.setText(m.getAuthor());

        category.setText(m.getCategories());

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what's your actual question.

Comment: I want to cache listview data that I receive from the server which means user will not have to always refresh the listview even when offline. For example if user a is offline, the last listview received from the server will be cache so that it can have access to it without the internet. Thanks for your reply.